# Remove older allocations details of a job in Nomad

Tags: nomad

When i check the status of a nomad job. Along with the new allocation i can see all the older allocations details(*with stop & complete*). The list is pretty huge.

Is there any way to remove/delete the older allocations details and **show only the latest allocation details**.

Answer (score 9):

Even if you garbage collect older allocations, nomad will keep its records of failed allocations. Use

```
nomad system reconcile summaries
```

on the command line, to remove older allocations from your summary. For details check out the [docs](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/commands/system/reconcile-summaries).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The fact that you see the old allocations means that nomad has not garbage collected the completed/failed allocations.
You can force a GC by calling the system API

```
curl -X PUT http://nomad:4646/v1/system/gc
```

Once nomad finishes the GC, you can see that the old allocations are cleared.

More information on [Nomad System API documentation](https://www.nomadproject.io/api/system.html#force-gc)

Comment: the full command would look like this: `curl -s -H "X-Nomad-Token: xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -XPUT http://nomad-host:4646/v1/system/gc`

Comment: or via cli: `nomad system gc`